# Define new section header and add text to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, cross-referencing

I would like to create a new section-type heading called assumption. The header must also appear in the Table of contents. So far I have managed to create the heading, but I ma failing to find a way to have it appear in the table of contents. I would like it to appear as a section would in the toc: Chapter number.headercounter-number, for example: 1.2 Assumption Header 1
Also, I created a new label format and would like the chapter number to also appear. See the attached MWE and kindly advise:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcounter{assumption}[section]
\newenvironment{assumption}[1][\unskip]{\large\refstepcounter{assumption}\medskip
\noindent{\textbf{Assumption~\thechapter.\theassumption. {\large}#1} \\} \addcontentsline{toc}{assumption} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\newcommand{\assumptionlabel}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}
\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Assumptions Chapter}
\assumption[Assumption Header]
\label{assumptionlabel:some-assumption}
Some assumption text.

\assumption[Assumption Header]
\label{assumptionlabel:some-assumption2}
Some assumption text with reference to Assumption \ref{assumptionlabel:some-assumption}.\\
Instead, I would like:\\
Some assumption text with reference to Assumption 1.1
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{assumption}
```

does not work, since `assumption` is no known `ToC` entry type like `section` etc, i.e. there is no `\l@assumption` macro yet, but this can be solved by

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@assumption\l@section
\makeatother
```

in order to use the relevant `\l@section` instead.

Now

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{assumption}{\protect\numberline{\theassumption}#1}
```

will provide the number and the title of the assumption in the ToC on `section` level.

Now for the label issue: Redefine `\@currentlabel` to make the cross-referencing format as desired, without explicit `\hypertarget` - statements -- `hyperref` is sophisticated enough to 'guarantee' correct hyper anchors if there are correct labels.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\assumptionname}{Assumption}
\newcounter{assumption}[section]
\makeatletter
\let\toclevel@assumption\toclevel@section% Providing bookmark support
\let\l@assumption\l@section

\newenvironment{assumption}[1][\unskip]{%
  \large\refstepcounter{assumption}%
  % Specific label format
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@assumption\endcsname\assumptionname\ \thechapter.\csname theassumption\endcsname}%
  \medskip%
  \noindent\textbf{\assumptionname~\thechapter.\theassumption.\ \large #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{assumption}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theassumption}#1}%
  \medskip% % Empty line here!!!
  \parindent0em

  \rmfamily%
}{\medskip}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Assumptions Chapter}
\begin{assumption}[Assumption Header]
\label{assumptionlabel:some-assumption}%
Some assumption text. \ref{assumptionlabel:some-assumption2}
\end{assumption}

\clearpage
\begin{assumption}[Assumption Header]
  \label{assumptionlabel:some-assumption2}
Some assumption text with reference to \ref{assumptionlabel:some-assumption}.
\end{assumption}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Updating for the label issue later on

Comment: Thank you for the toc edit. It works well. Looking forward to the labelling issue.

Comment: @TNP: As it stands, your `\assumptionlabel` command is not used yet. I don't know what you want to achieve with that, actually. In a normal setup, applying `\label` and `hyperref` should do what you want, without explicit `\hypertarget` calls

Comment: Also you're misusing the `\assumption` -- it should be `\begin{assumption}...\end{assumption}` rather

Comment: With using \label and the hyperref package, I get the "Assumption 1" in  the cross-reference. I would like instead "Assumption 1.1". I could have used the native sectioning commands, but I wanted to define my own with that particular format. Is it possible to emulate the "section" cross-referencing format for my created header?

Comment: I must add this. I have a chapter: "Model Formulation", a section: "Modelling Assumptions" and under this section I want to have numbered assumptions with the chapter number and assumption number. I therefore couldn't use the subsection command for each assumption, hence I looked to create a new section header called "assumption", which will have an identical numbering format to the "section" command.

Comment: @TNP: See the update please